# Get data from below json string

Tags: javascript, json

I want to get the value of "text" from below code with javascript. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
<script> require("InitialJSLoader").handleServerJS({
    
    "require": [

        ["ODNavigation", "setPageQuery", [],
            [{
                "structure": [{
                    "text": "name",
                    "type": "none",
                    "uid": 00001
                }],
                "semantic": null
            }]
        ]
    ]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = {"require": [

    ["ODNavigation", "setPageQuery", [],
        [{
            "structure": [{
                "text": "name",
                "type": "none",
                "uid": 00001
            }],
            "semantic": null
        }]
    ]
]}

r.require[0][3][0].structure[0].text // return "name"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
    "require": [

        ["ODNavigation", "setPageQuery", [],
            [{
                "structure": [{
                    "text": "name",
                        "type": "none",
                        "uid": 00001
                }],
                    "semantic": null
            }]
        ]
    ]
};
var text = obj.require[0][3][0].structure[0].text;
alert(text);
```